# Completion of direct sum of Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have a family of Banach spaces $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, each with norm $\|\cdot\|_{n}$. Consider the algebraic direct sum $X = \bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}}X_{n}$, defined as the space of sequences $x=(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ which have only finitely many nonzero entries. This is a vector space which can be equipped with the norm:
$$\|x\| = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\|x_{n}\|_{n}$$
My question is: is the completion $\hat{X}$ of $X$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$ the space of all sequences $x=(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, $x_{n} \in X_{n}$, such that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\|x_{n}\|_{n} <\infty?$

On one hand, if $x = (x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence such that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\|x_{n}\|_{n} < \infty$ then one can define a sequence $\{y_{N}\}_{N \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $y_{N} = (y_{n}^{N})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by $y_{n}^{N} = x_{n}$ if $n \le N$ and zero otherwise. This way, $\{y_{N}\}_{N \in \mathbb{N}}\in X$ and $y_{N}\to x$. Because $\hat{X}$ is complete,  $x \in \hat{X}$.

But I am not sure about the other inclusion.

Comment: Yes. It can be proven in the same way as $\ell^1$ is complete.

Comment: @OnurOktay let me see if I understand. I can use the same proof that $\ell^{1}$ is complete to show that the space of summable sequences $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\|x_{n}\|_{n} < \infty$ is complete. Then, I use the reasoning on my post to show that $X$ is dense in the space of summable spaces. Because completion is unique up to isomorphisms, we are done. Am I correct?

Comment: Sound like a great outline for the proof. Can you fill in the necessary details into it and post as an answer?